# Jquery dropdown menu vertical

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to do a dropdown menu vertical with a twitter bootstrap. My dropdown links are a same class CSS. But when I choose one if them, the two dropdown links slide.

Thanks for your help.

```
<ul class="nav nav-list">
 <li class="nav-header"><a href="">Ac</a></li>
 <li class="nav-header main"><a href="">Pla</a>
  <ul>
    <li class="nav-subheader"><a href="">Qua</a></li>
    <li class="nav-subheader"><a href="">Qua1</a></li>
    <li class="nav-subheader"><a href="">Qua2</a></li>
 </ul></li>

<li class="nav-header main"><a href="">Proj</a>
 <ul>
   <li class="nav-subheader"><a href="#/1">Sou</a></li>
   <li class="nav-subheader"><a href="#/2">Sou1</a></li>
   <li class="nav-subheader"><a href="#/3">Sou2</a></li>
   <li class="nav-subheader"><a href="#/4">Sou3</a></li>
 </ul></li>

  <li class="nav-header"><a href="">Cen</a></li>
  <li class="nav-header"><a href="">Mes</a></li>
 </ul>
```

Comment: Could you set up a jsFiddle for us, and also explain your problem in a little more detail.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a few key classes and information.

See the jFiddle I've created:
http://jsfiddle.net/KhCrm/

Make sure you have included the relevant JS/CSS (The only 2 needed to make this work really are dropdown.js, and the bootstrap.css.

Comment: In fact, when I click on one dropdown link, both links dropdown slide downa and show each their submenu